# Eliminate NULL values in data with other needed data

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    [hMy],
    [hAmendment],
    [hDeal],
    [hTenant],
    [hCommClauseLib],
    [sName],
    [sDesc],
    [sReference], 
    [ClauseDate],
    [hUserCreatedBy],
    [dtCreated],
    [hUserModifiedBy],
    [dtLastModified],
    [hForeignDb],
    [sExtReference],
    [iClauseStatus],
    [dtClauseEndDate],
    [hCopyFrom],
    [hUnit],
    [sDescHtml]
    [tRowVersion]
FROM 
    [dbo].[CommClauses]
```

Some of these columns of data have plenty of null values mixed with values we need. How do i get rid of all the null values in the entire data set that i am trying to workbench into DOMO

Comment: "Get rid of them"?   Meaning what?

Comment: Might be worth trying "ISNUL(...)" or "COALESCE(...)"...

Comment: ..or maybe `WHERE SomeColumn IS NOT NULL`.   the question isn't clear.

Comment: Eliminate the record of all NULL values ?   We'd like to help you, but your question is ambiguous at best.

Comment: @DavidBrown . . . Please provide sample data and desired results so it is clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Hi All, Sorry for leaving the question so open ended. that data we are pulling from is thousands of rows of data and in colums Sreference there are 1000 pieces of data we need and another 9k that are null but in column hForeignDB there is no data and is all null. How do I get rod of null values in the one column of data that has some good data but also ignore the column that has 99% null values? Thanks

Comment: You can eliminate ROWS by adding a where clause. You can substitute null values in your columns using ISNULL or COALESCE. But your goal is still very much unclear. Time for a simple example of a few rows that you retrieve and what you want changed in that resultset. Otherwise, this is likely to be closed as <unclear what you are asking>.

Answer (score 2):

Try build your SQL query like this:

```
SELECT 
    [hMy],
    [hAmendment],
    [...],
FROM 
    [dbo].[CommClauses]
WHERE 
    [hMy] IS NOT NULL 
    AND [hAmendment] IS NOT NULL 
    AND [...] IS NOT NULL;
```